# Upper bound for the total number of paths between every pair of vertices of a functional digraph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have looked for it, but haven't found anything.

What I'm asking is an upper bound for the number of paths between every pair of vertices on a functional digraph (digraphs where the outdegree of each vertex is at most 1). But a solution for a digraph is valid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a functional digraph with $n$ vertices. There are $n(n-1)$ ordered pairs of vertices $(v_1,v_2)$ in $G$. Since each vertex has at most one edge pointing outwards, there is at most one path from $v_1$ to $v_2$ in any digraph.

If $G$ is a directed $n$-cycle, then for every order pair of vertices $(v_1,v_2)$ in $G$, there is a directed path from $v_1$ to $v_2$. Thus the total number of paths is $n(n-1)$.

Therefore the maximum number of paths in any functional digraph on $n$-vertices is $n(n-1)$, and that maximum is achieved if $G$ is a directed $n$-cycle.